# jQuery's Dialog breaking Chrome's CSS

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have the following problem. When I activate a dialog window that is very large (around 400px in height), when I close it in Chrome, the browser displays the vertical scroll, and at the bottom of the window I find a new "white" bar (that, is, as though as the content isn't as long as the body's height). The problem is that I check, and the body's height hasn't changed, the content's height hasn't changed... and this problem disappears if I, for instance, right-click somewhere to display a ContextMenu, or hover over a CSS DropDown menu.

Has this ever happened to anybody? Any idea why it may be happening? I find that, if I change the top attribute of the dialog box when it is shown to 0 (putting it in the top of the screen instead of the middle), when I close it I don't see this glitch happening.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Heathcliff

Would you be able to provide a link to the website your having a problem with? or the html adn css so i can test it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I was hoping this could be a generic problem people are aware of, not something particular about my application. If it is so, then don't worry.